# Rails: Why do I get the error "undefined method `model_name'" when trying to use nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes

I have a model that accepts nested attributes for another model it belongs to.

```rb
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer, required: true
  belongs_to :collection_address,
             class_name: 'Address',
             foreign_key: :collection_address_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collection_address
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```rb
def update
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @collection_address = @order.collection_address || @order.build_collection_address

  if @order.update(strong_params)
    flash[:success] = 'Order updated'
    redirect_to order_path(@order)
  else
    flash.now[:warning] = @order.errors.full_messages
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

My edit form looks like this:

```rb
<h1>Edit order</h1>
<%= simple_form_for @order, url: order_path do |form| %>
    <%= form.simple_fields_for @collection_address do |address_form| %>
      <%= address_form.input :address1 %>
      <%= address_form.input :address2 %>
      <%= address_form.input :city %>
      <%= address_form.input :postcode %>
    <% end %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

But when I try to load the page, Rails fails with the error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 128ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms | Allocations: 7986)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <h1>Edit order</h1>
    2: <%= simple_form_for @order, url: order_path do |form| %>
    3:     <%= form.simple_fields_for @collection_address do |address_form| %>
    4:       <%= address_form.input :address1 %>
    5:       <%= address_form.input :address2 %>
    6:       <%= address_form.input :city %>

actionview (6.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/model_naming.rb:11:in `model_name_from_record_or_class'
actionview (6.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:2170:in `fields_for'
simple_form (4.1.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/builder.rb:28:in `simple_fields_for'
...
```

The nested fields are definitely causing this because when I remove the nested form, the page loads correctly. All I can think of it that it's something to do with the association having a different class name from its association name (that is, the association is `:collection_address` but its class name is `Address`).

From here on, I'm completely stuck. Does anyone know why my form is failing to load? Have I missed something obvious? Is there an extra step I need to take? How can I get the form to work with nested attributes for `collection_address`?

Comment: You provided your update action but I have a sneaky suspicion that `@collection_address` is not defined in your edit action

Comment: You're right. I'm tired.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to define `@collection_address` in the edit action.